# Angular Guard: Checking HTTP-Only Cookie Auth on Server- CanActivateFn

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a HTTP only cookie Auth Method;
server:

```
export const checkCookie = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const token = req.cookies["token"];
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
  }
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET);
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, userId: decoded.id });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
  }
};
```

the route for this API call is:
GET `localhost:8000/api/v1/login`

and router guard in Angular:

```
import { CanActivateFn } from '@angular/router';
import axios from 'axios';

export const loginAuthGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  return true;
};
```

How to send a request from this quard to this endpoint to check this Http only cookin using `CanActivateFn` that is modern and automaticly generated?

Comment: Guards can also return promises. So you can create another async method, that will use checkCookie, and map response to biolean. Then just use that method in guard

Answer (score 1):

I think the best choise for you is [resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)

Just keep in mind, that resolvers called after guards, so if you decided not only use resolver but the guard too, you will need to handle that problem manually.

Comment: thank sir for knowledge and for help!

Answer (score 0):

Its no possible to inject HttpClient directly into the `loginAuthGuard`, It would have been much cleaner. but you can use `AuthService` that will perform the http request an return true if succesfull, and easily inject it with [inject](https://angular.io/api/core/inject)(...).

Just played with this example in the [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateFn#description):

```
class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  checkLoginStatus(): Observable<boolean> {
    //return true if http is successfull.
    );
  }
}

export const loginAuthGuard: CanActivateFn = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
) => {
  return inject(AuthService).checkLoginStatus();
};
```

Comment: thank sir for knowledge and for help!